# Give an example of: groovyc --sourcepath

Tags: groovy

I am unable to get the `--sourcepath` option of groovyc to work at all.  Can someone furnish a trivial example of it actually doing anything?

Ultimately I want to use "groovyc" at the command line with a directory a packaged organized tree of mixed groovy and java source.  I don't want to reference each source file explicitly.  And I don't want to use an ant or maven task either, on grounds of both principle (hey is there a bug here?) and because the production scenario that I might want to tweak the source in has neither but will have groovy.  I know I could use unix `find` but must I resort to that?!

Comment: Why not use `gradle`, then you can distribute a `gradlew` wrapper (just type `gradle wrapper` in the root of your project to generate) and the other people don't need to have gradle installed, the wrapper will install a local version for them

Comment: Sorry but this misses the point.  "groovyc" exists; and I'd like to understand how to use it (including a documented option "--sourcepath") without having to specify the path to all source files.  If it doesn't work then a bug should be filed.  If nobody uses it because 100% of users use ant, maven, gradle, etc. then it should be removed.

Comment: True, sorry I was trying to provide you with a possible workaround in case you were stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sourcepath` isn't used anymore. It's only there for backwards compatibility and will be removed in the future.

The Groovy documentation is currently rewritten, you can find a snapshot including the documentation for `groovyc` here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20288797/groovy-documentation/index.html#ThegroovycAntTask-groovyc

Comment: Hm; I'm having trouble accessing that URL. Is there a trunk/master branch version of the documentation in source control you can point me to?  Judging from the anchor tag I see a reference to 'Ant' but to be clear I'm not interested in using Ant in this scenario. I'd love to just point groovyc at a directory and have it do its thing.

Comment: Currently, no. You need to checkout the "documentation" branch (https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/tree/documentation) and execute the following command:
`./gradlew assembleAsciidoc`

Comment: It would be *really* nice if groovyc could accept a source path instead of explicitly referencing each source file.